# Alternative to override extension's method

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

I want to extend `UIView` by adding some functions, and override them in any subclass of `UIView` that I want. I found in apple documentations that I can't override extensions (and the compiler will complain) which make some sense. So

I need someone to suggest an alternative way to the below:

```
extension UIView { 
  func hide() { //do almost nothing } 
}

class myLabel: UILabel { 
  override func hide() { 
    //do work on uilabel that can't be done on imgView
  }
}

class myImageView: UIImageView {
 override func hide() { 
    //do work on imgView that can't be done on uilabel
  }
}
```

And the reason I want this is that later in my code I will face the below code and I have to many subclasses and I don't want to write too many `if-lets` trying to cast the `view` to `myLabel, myTextView, myImageView... etc`

```
let view = cell.viewWithTag(someTag)
// and I want to write this below without casting
view.hide()
```

I tried with `protocols` and `protocol extensions` but I couldn't make it though.

**Any thoughts?**

---

Note: `func hide()` is just an example. My func will have more to do.
**Question updated to be clear.

Comment: Subclass `UIView` and then have your UIView's subclass *that* subclass.  If you need different behaviour then an extension isn't the right way to go.

Comment: I need to implement `hide()` func in many places.
I have `myLabel: UILabel {}` and `myImgView: UIImageView {}` .. etc
so I can't subclass `UIView` because if I made `myLabel: myView` then I won't be able to make it subclass of the `UILabel`.

Comment: You either have a common implementation in which case you extend `UIView`, or you need to either subclass or extend each of the existing `UIView` subclasses

Comment: yes, but have you considered `protocols`?
When I see some protocols like `Hashable`, I feel that I can create my own protocol to solve this but I still don't know how. Do you think `protocols` could help?

Comment: You could use a protocol, but you would still need to extend each relevant UIView subclass to adopt that protocol and provide an implementation for that class.  All a protocol does is define the methods that the extension needs to implement.  You could use an extension to the protocol itself to provide a default implementation, negating the need to write specific code in the case where the default implementation was sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Updating answer to make use of protocols also

Protocols does in various ways enable to you replace subclassing in some cases however you still need your class to conform to the protocol to be able to see and override those methods

You can have a protocol for example:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    func hide()
}
```

To do what you are intending to do it is best to have a parent subclass UIView with all functions that can be overridden for example (in this updated answer you can have your methods to override inside the protocol and have your subclasses conform to it):

```
class ParentView : UIView, SomeProtocol {
    func hide() {
        print("PARENT")
    }

    func anyOtherMethod() {

    }
}
```

and then have all the other UIView's that need to override those methods subclass `ParentView`:

```
class ViewOne : ParentView {
    override func hide() {
        print("VIEW ONE")
    }
}

class ViewTwo : ParentView {
    override func hide() {
        print("VIEW TWO")
    }
}
```

So even if you later place this code:

```
let view = cell.viewWithTag(someTag)
// and I want to write this below without casting
view.hide()
```

you won't need to explicitly cast your UIView's, the view will call it's intended overridden method, unless and until you call `super` in your overridden method also

**EDIT:** More on making use of protocols

In the case you need other controls to also have a `hide()` method to override then you can still have to subclass, for example in the case of UILabel you need to override it:

```
class ParentLabel : UILabel, SomeProtocol {
    func hide() {
        print("PARENT LABEL")
    }
}
```

then you can write the intended code with casting to your protocol

```
if let view = cell.viewWithTag(someTag) as? SomeProtocol {
    view.hide() // prints PARENT LABEL
}
```

and either use that subclassed UILabel control or if you need in some cases some label to override that behavior then you can still create a child subclass of `ParentLabel`:

```
class LabelOne : ParentLabel {
    override func hide() {
        print("LABEL ONE")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for you help. I updated the example in the question, you will find that subclassing in not the solution in this case.

Comment: Yeah i saw it once i posted the question, I see you're looking for protocols as answer but that won't work as well, you will still need to subclass and apply your protocol to your subclassed view so that it can see the methods to override inside the protocols

Comment: I used your answer using the protocols, but I couldn't write this line `view.hide()` because view `UIView` still needs to conform to `SomeProtocol`.

Comment: I used your answer and modify it a little bit and It worked for me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No worries, as long as it worked for you, it would be great if you can select my answer as well, you can edit your modification to it as well

Comment: You don’t need to subclass `UILabel`, you can just make `UILabel` adopt the protocol with an extension. `extension UILabel: Hideable {…}`

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, you are right. It's just in my case I have my own controls. Thank you.